# Eclipse не видит Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

Я установил Android Studio и вместе с ней Android SDK. И так как у меня в данный момент нет возможности пользоваться Android Studio, я решил работать в Eclipse. Я установил все что было необходимо (кроме Android SDK, он у меня уже был). В Eclipse работает Android SDK Manager и AVD. Но когда я создаю проект (в папке eclipse-worksplace) у меня в консоль выводятся ошибки

> C:\Users\Oleg\eclipse-workspace\MyProjectt\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

И еще куча предупреждений:[image: Предупреждения]

Comment: `AppCompat` нет в `SDK` - это из библиотек поддержки (`support` или `AndroidX`). Вам нужно подключить нужную библиотеку, либо использовать  темы и классы из `SDK`

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог такой способ, в стилях измените:

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat">
    ...
</style>
```

на:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    ...
</style>
```

возможно проблема и в другом месте, но при возникновении ошибки у меня этот способ работал.